# Finding the y-axis for points on a line graph made with PHP's imageline()

Tags: php, math

I'm making a line graph with PHP using imagecreate() and imageline(). Im' trying to figure out how to do the calculation to find the y-axis for each point on the graph.

Here are a few values that would go in the graph:

```
$values[jan] = .84215;
$values[feb] = 1.57294;
$values[mar] = 3.75429;
```

Here is an example of the line graph. The x-axis labels are positioned at the vertical middle of the x-axis lines. The gap between the x-axis lines is 25px.

How would you do the calculation to find the y-axis for the values in the array above?

```
5.00
4.75
4.50
4.25
4.00
3.75
3.50
3.25
3.00
2.75
2.50
2.25
2.00
1.75
1.50
1.25
1.00
0.75
0.50
0.25
0.00
     Jan  Feb  Mar  apr  may  jun  jul  aug  sep  oct  nov  dec
```

Comment: I would first use a pencil and some paper to figure it out and then if I get stuck with the math to ask somewhere else, not here,

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to map any floating point number between `[0.00 5.00]` to your Y-axis points.

The granularity of your Y-axis is `0.25`. So you can divide the input by `0.25` to get the exact point on the Y-axis. But this value could be between two point for example input is `0.3` and `0.3/0.25` is `1.`2 and there is not `1.2` on the Y-axis.

To solve this we associate a range `+|-0.125` with each Y-axis number. So 1.0 will have the range `0.75` to `1.25`, this any input with input/0.25 falling in [0.75 1.25] will have `1.00` as its Y-axis point.

In PHP you can do this as:

```
$Y_cord = ceil ( $input / 0.25 - 0.125) * 0.25;
```

You can see the mapping of a random dataset [**here**](http://www.ideone.com/ZL1w0).